# Storing post data in array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, post

I am using cakephp to mess around with sending receiving data through post...
How do I store an array coming in as post data into an array declared inside the controller? I'm doing this:

```
$data = array();
      if($this->request->is('post')){
      $data =$this->request->data;
        debug($data);
```

But it's displaying this as response:

```
array()
```

Please help!

PS-I'm using inbuilt methods to post data via URL using REST. eg. i post to /localhost/cakephp/users.json to send the following data in json: {"user":"asdasd","pass":"asdas"}. I just need some way to compare it with login password in my database but I can't find out if i'm receiving the data!

Comment: How do you know you're actually sending post data to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the data with ajax, is your contentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  I've had empty $this->data field in the controller, if I post as application/json.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This would make a really great comment. Answers need to be specific and as certain as possible, so this really isn't a good answer. Yes, I know you don't have enough rep to comment yet. You'll just have to wait. It'll come.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)

```
$data=$this->request->input('json_decode');
```

This saves the post json request into a variable called $data.

```
$this->set(array(
                          'data' => $data,
              '_serialize' => array('data')));
```

Afterwards, the above code can be used to send back that same data as JSON response.